# spark dataframe concatenate column name to values

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have a dataframe which I want to modify in a way that each row
will containt the column name .
for example :

```
FirstName LastName
Jhon       Doe
David      Lue
```

to create the follwing

```
(FirstName=Jhon,LastName=Doe)
(FirstName=David,LastName=Lue)
```

I managed to do for df with 2 columns

```scala
val x = df.map { row => (names(0) + "=" +row(0) , names(1)+"="+rows(1)}
```

but how can I do it with for loop for any number of columns?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

One option is to use foldLeft on the column names:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

import sqlContext.implicits._
val df = Seq(
  ("John", "Doe"),
  ("David", "Lue")
).toDF("first_name", "last_name")

val x = df.columns.foldLeft(df) {
  (acc: DataFrame, colName: String) => 
    acc.withColumn(colName, concat(lit(colName + "="), col(colName)))
}

x.show()
```

Resulting in:

```
+----------------+-------------+
|      first_name|    last_name|
+----------------+-------------+
| first_name=John|last_name=Doe|
|first_name=David|last_name=Lue|
+----------------+-------------+
```

If you then want to convert it to an RDD of tuples, you can call a map on it:

```scala
x.rdd.map(r => (r.getString(0), r.getString(1)))
```

or even with Spark SQL's typed API:

```
x.as[(String, String)].rdd
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It worked like a charm. Since Im a new user, my marking it as the right answer is calculated but not displayed. Thanks Again!